# MySql Connector SQL Statement does not return any values under java

Tags: java, mysql

I am using mySQL Connector in java and I need to write this long query where I join tables and return stocks of particular user. User_ID would be supplied by the java program hence i got ? and passed into the database. However I assume due to syntax error in java it does not return any values to program and simply fails. Query works perfectly in database.

```
 String a = jTextField_User_Name.getText();
     PreparedStatement ps = null;

     String queryretrive = "SELECT DISTINCT Stock_Name FROM stockname,users,stock,userstock WHERE 'users.ID' = ? AND users.ID = userstock.User_ID AND userstock.Stock_ID = stock.Stock_ID AND stock.Stock_ID = stockname.Stock_ID";

    ResultSet rs;
     try {
        ps = MyConnector.getConnection().prepareStatement(queryretrive);

        ps.setString(1,a);


        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())
        {
              System.out.println(rs.getString("Stock_Name"));

        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to try catch the error and show it to us.

Comment: @nbk I edited the answer showing full function with try and catch. It simply goes to else statement.

Comment: if there is a problem in ps.executeQuery() you wont see it because your catch has no code to display errors

Comment: I removed comment from catch but it doesn't display anything. This catch fully works on another statement. I think way java syntax is wrong for this query.

Comment: Try to use \`users.ID\` (in backward quotes) instead of 'users.ID' or without quotes at all. Using single quotes you say that string literal 'users.ID' is equal to passed parameter which is, probably, not what you want

Comment: Your query is old and outdated, so get back to the drawing board and use proper joins which exist for many years. After checking your code i have a guess and your query returns nothing at all.and you haven't checked it in workbench

Comment: @nbk It fully works in database. This is how we learned and I have to do it this way unfortunately.

Comment: no it doesn't **'users.ID'**   is a string and you compare it to what ever you bind to it , so you haven't tested it. please use joins instead of comma ion From

Comment: @NickRyan that returns error of com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'users.ID' in 'where

Answer (score 1):

> `WHERE 'users.ID' = ? AND users.ID =`

Obviously, the second reference to `users.ID` doesn't need to be quoted, so why did you attempt to quote the first one?

Anyway, in MySQL `"` and `'` are used to quote [string literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) and `` ` `` (backtick) is used to quote [identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html). If `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode is enabled, then `"` is used to quote identifiers, like other DBMS dialects do.

If you do need to quote, you need to quote each part separately, so the correct quoting would be `` `users`.`ID` `` or `"users"."ID"`.

The fact that `'` sometimes work for quoting identifiers is just weird lenient behavior and shouldn't be used, since it easily confused with string literals. Don't even know how MySQL decides whether it's a string literal or an identifier, so it's best to never do it.

Comment: Because it had = ? which I was passing value to. I already solved it but thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

this query is not long but this is hard to understand without your data model and code example.

if this is working in MySQLWorkBench should works from java. If this is not working from java you have poor error handling, or you haven't set properly parameter.

'users.ID' may be just users.ID

remove try/catch for testing purpose or handle this catch.

BTW.
With java/mysql ALWAYS handle finally to free connection, something like :

```
finally
{
    try {if (rs != null) rs.close();} catch(Exception e) {}
    try {if (statement != null) statement.close();} catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: I catch the errors but it doesn't go to error but to else statement. So I guess rs.next never occurs. It works in phpmyadmin but not in java.

Comment: then parameter is wrong. put literal for testing purpose.

Comment: what does that mean sorry I am new to this.

Comment: BTW: With Java JDBC (not just MySQL), use try-with-resource to close Connections, Statements and ResultSets, not `finally` blocks.